# AjaxFileUpload control don't upload .dmp files

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to use AjaxFileUpload to upload dmp file asynchronously in a asp.net website. Other files are uploaded successfully but when i try to upload a dmp file it shows error in red. No issue with the size and max no of files. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because ".dmp" file extension is not whitelisted.

Add `additionalUploadFileExtensions` attribute to the Web.config:

```
<ajaxControlToolkit additionalUploadFileExtensions="dmp" />
```

More info can be found in project's [wiki](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/AjaxFileUpload-setup#allowed-file-extensions).